# How to set my webpage to maintenance mode from CMS?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, content-management-system

I'm working on my first web page and I can't solve one problem. I'm making CMS maintenance settings. I want to make option (drop down) to change index from index.php to maintenance.php.

My site looks like this:

/cms/

index.php

maintenance.php

If I rename maintenance.php to index.php, CMS still works (I left log in area for admin to get in).

So, my question: is this most logical way switch to maintenance mode? If yes, then how? Or maybe there is more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a form field that toggles maintenance mode on and off (a zero or a one in the database). Then you can query that row before your your index.php `html` tag. if the maintenance mode row returns a 1, forward the user to the maintenance.php page.

```
<?php
// query your database for the maintenance mode boolean
if($maintenance == '1') header('Location: http://www.example.com/maintenance.php');
?>
<html>
```

Alternatively, you could do all of this in the index.php page with and if/else statement:

```
</head>
<body>
<?php
  // query your database for the maintenance mode boolean
  if($maintenance == '1') include('maintenance.php');
  else{
?>
<div id="homepage">
</div>
<? } // end else ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sometimes something is so simple yet so hard for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make 'maintenance mode' symlink 'maintenance.php' to 'index.php'? When you turn it off, delete the symlink and make 'index.php' point to 'realindex.php'